# readAsDataURL 404 - Image preview FileReader()

Tags: javascript

I'm using `FileReader` to preview multiple images that have been selected using an HTML Input.

[Here's what I've tried so far](https://jsfiddle.net/d05086vs/)

The issue I'm having, is when I fill in all the details, in Firebug I get the following error:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.example.com/[object%20HTMLImageElement]"

I understand using `readAsDataURL` may cause this issue because it's trying to read a URL of a non existent image, although this may not be the cause of the issue.

One other consideration I have, I plan to have a maximum of 9 images. My understanding is the uploaded image is converted to base64, and you show the image by using this large string in the image `src""` attribute. Would this cause an issue with memory? I would accept no larger than 1MB images, however I would imagine the memory used would be more than 1MB per image.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi. What's the end goal? Just to display the preview image?

In terms of memory, I don't see any real issue in temporarily storing 9 images in memory.

Comment: @mcranston18 The end goal is to display the image, along with the text as a complete element (like it would once published on my site). This all happens within the  `append()` block

Answer (score 0):

The preview image is not showing because you are not appending the image to any DOM element. I created an empty div called `.image-container` and appended the image to the container during the `load` event.

```
app.fileReader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  app.imgElement.src = event.target.result;
  $('.image-container').append(app.imgElement)
});
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d05086vs/5/